# how to find whether datacolumn row value contains string or integer

Tags: c#

i have an datatable  with column  unit.
 here column name  is unit

unit

abc

123

ass

ttt

here i need  to  check whether  the   row  value  conatins string  or integer

thanks
prince

Comment: And what have you tried? What didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some examples on how you can check this. But you question is not to clear, when and how do you need to check the values?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/84990ad2-5046-472b-b103-f862bfcd5dbc/
http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/IsNumeric.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`DataColumn` has a `DataType` property - this will tell you what the column is using.